# What happened to ~ when updating oh-my-zsh?

Tags: osx, bash, zsh

Not sure what changed the meaning of the home path `~` in my zsh.
So when I do `cd ~` , I don't `cd` into my home but it gives me an error that `/Users/carlos` does not exist.

How can I reset `~` to refer to the current user again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [recent update](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/commit/aaca1c25582fce211d8f94179e93d736961ea2fd) slipped in a...

```
HOME="/home/carlos"
```

Remove the file `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/totvs.sh` to fix it.

You can also run `upgrade_oh_my_zsh`. If you've made the change above, navigate to `/Users/user/.oh-my-zsh` and execute `git checkout .`.

Comment: I figured something went wrong with oh-my-zsh so I uninstalled and reinstalled - all's ok now - thanks